# 'Go on a binge' in British English?

Tags: phrases, british-english

If said without any accompanying information, is 'go on a binge' primarily understood by Brits as meaning a 'drinking binge'?

Comment: Forty or fifty years ago, I'd have said yes...but these days, with the word applying to eating and to TV watching, I think it's a matter of opinion. Obviously, context would usually fill in the blanks.

Comment: Apart from OED, which lists meanings in historical order, there are other dictionaries which do list "prevalent sense first". What has your own research shown? Please add that into the question, to save others from looking it up as well.

Comment: It depends on the context. If it's a context where drinking would make sense, then probably yes; but that wouldn't apply every time. I don't see how it would ever be said without accompanying information because you'd probably specify who was on the binge, or some location or consequence. Unless you have an example?

Comment: Merriam-Webster is also a historical dictionary (listing meanings in _historical_ order).

Comment: I'd say the most common usage nowadays involves watching streamed series.

Comment: @alphabet, while the other question overlaps with this one, it does not focus on whether *binge* is 'primarily understood by Brits as meaning a 'drinking binge'. A significant component of the other question is whether one can say 'There was a binge', which diminishes the usefulness of that page to those who may be seeking the answer to the specific question posed here. The other question is also not specific to British English. Why don't you just post here some, suitably edited, version of your answer to the other question, rather than voting to close this one?

Comment: binge and binging is not just drinking: gambling binge. Anything done in excess: binge watching TV series.

Answer (score 1):

The Cambridge English Dictionary gives, as it first definition of 'binge', the following.

> an occasion when an activity is done in an extreme way, especially eating, drinking, or spending money:

- a drinking/eating/spending binge
- He went on a five day drinking binge.

So here, whereas the word without the full OP phrase covers any form of overindulgence, the addition of the phrase "go on" brings up booze immediately, which suggests that this vernacular or colloquial usage does conjure up the booze.

Note, however, that (and I am speaking for myself here) one further suggestion is that in my experience (for what that is worth) people who want to apply the 'go on a binge' with something other than the booze insert the specific indulgence before the word *binge*.  Thus they might go on a shopping, or reading or eating binge, but not feel the need to specify 'drinking'.

Collins is not entirely clear on this point.

> If you go on a binge, you do too much of something, such as drinking alcohol, eating, or spending money.

It mentions drinking alcohol first, but that could easily because it is listing the vices an alphabetic rather than frequency or even random order.

Merriam Webster, a leading American dictionary offers no definite answer to this dilemma.

> especially : an act of excessive or compulsive consumption (as of food or alcoholic beverages)
> went on an eating/drinking binge
> Meanwhile, the hangover cure pitches suggest that before every healthy New Year's resolution comes an unhealthy New Year's binge.

This suggests a predominant association between 'going on a binge' and the stomach, but whether alcoholic or solid is not certain.

So what others are likely to understand by "My friend Bob is going on a binge" will depend on what they and the speaker knows about Bob and perhaps their own preoccupations with alcoholic drinking.

So unrestrained food and/or alcoholic consumption is clearly associated with the raw expression 'going on a binge'.  But the association is such that it would not be a good idea to seek clarification unless your knowledge of the people is such that it is bound to be about the booze.

Comment: Anything done in excess: gambling binge or even (if you dislike poetry) a poetry-writing binge. And this is not only BrE.

Comment: Yes, all these can be understood by 'go on a binge'.  Nevertheless, addressing the question, the tendency of the three dictionaries I cited to head straight in their definitions and examples for alcohol and food gives some credibility of the idea in the question that the phrase 'go on a binge', in the absence of any additional modifier or explanation (such as 'revision binge' or 'opera binge' etc.),  is quite likely to  be taken by a listener to be understood to be about excessive booze or food.